# How to emit the "F5 key pressed event" through Serial Port?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm writing an application that communicates through serial port device, and I want to write a command that will input the F5 key.

my code is:

```
int main()
    {
    SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort("COM7", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    myPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    try
    {

        if (!(myPort.IsOpen))

            myPort.Open();

    }

    catch

    {

    }  
}
```

I want to add something like:

```
myPory.write(/*the value for the F5 key*/);
```

How can I do it??

Comment: There is no concept of "F5 key" in serial communication and it is unlikely you are emulating keyboard (I don't think regular PC keyboard is supports serial protocol, but it is just my guess). Please clarify what you need to send OR what listens for that "F5" command on other end.

Comment: the other side waits for the key F5 to be pressed in order to know if to show boot menu options. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In serial port communication you can send only bytes. The receiver will decide how to interpret it, so there is no way to send F5 key. 
You can only send F5 code as byte.

```
Keys.F5 (in bytes 116)
```